# Drawing rectangles in web application that show screen position from windows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have an input string like this:

```
{ (3200, 1080), (1280, 0) ; (1280, 1024), (0, 0) }
```

which is basically an input I get from my c# program which takes the coordinates of my screens.

The numbers in brackets are coordinates of the lower right and upper left point and define a rectangle. For example:

```
(1280, 1024), (0, 0)
```

means that the first screen has dimensions 1280 x 1024 and starts in the upper left point (0,0). Next to it is the second screen which upper left point is at coordinate (1280, 0) and its lower right coordinate is at point (3200, 1080) - and they form a rectangle.

What I have to do is draw these screen in an web application - nothing fancy just two different colored rectangles would do. Now, I did a little research and saw that html5 canvas might be the way to go, but I want to hear what you think and maybe give me a push in the right direction. If you could give some jsfiddle example that would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to draw something *inside* the rectangles? If you don't, using DIVs with `position:absolute` should do it.

Comment: @bfavaretto: actually no, nothing will be in the rectangles. I wonder if you could share some example of what you mean? Cause, I thought that that way (with divs) would be harder - hmm, maybe I am wrong - thx, will try.

Comment: Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpHC4/)

Comment: @bfavaretto: thank you, put this in a comment so I can mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Okay, compiled my comments as a proper answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use DIVs with `position: absolute`, as detailed on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpHC4/) (jQuery used for the sake of simplicity, but the same can easily be accomplished without jQuery).

edit (I just added the code if for some reason your jsfiddle gets deleted!):

HTML:

```
<div id="screens">
    <div id="screen0" class="screen"></div>
    <div id="screen1" class="screen"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#screens { position: relative }
.screen {position: absolute }

#screen0 { background: blue; }
#screen1 { background: green; }
```

JS:

```
var originalScreens = [
    {
        position: [0,0],
        dimensions: [1280,1024]
    },
    {
        position: [1280,0],
        dimensions: [1090,1080]
    }
];
var scale = 0.1;
for(var i=0; i<originalScreens.length; i++) {
    $('#screen' + i).css('left', (originalScreens[i].position[0] * scale) + 'px');
    $('#screen' + i).css('top', (originalScreens[i].position[1] * scale) + 'px');

    $('#screen' + i).css('width', (originalScreens[i].dimensions[0] * scale) + 'px');
    $('#screen' + i).css('height', (originalScreens[i].dimensions[1] * scale) + 'px');
}
```